# How do I convert an enum reference to a number?

Tags: rust

I have an enum:

```
enum Foo {
    Bar = 1,
}
```

How do I convert a reference to this enum into an integer to be used in math?

```
fn f(foo: &Foo) {
    let f = foo as u8;  // error[E0606]: casting `&Foo` as `u8` is invalid
    let f = foo as &u8; // error[E0605]: non-primitive cast: `&Foo` as `&u8`
    let f = *foo as u8; // error[E0507]: cannot move out of borrowed content
}
```

Answer (score 99, accepted):

`*foo as u8` is correct, but you have to implement `Copy` because otherwise you would leave behind an invalid reference.

```
#[derive(Copy, Clone)]
enum Foo {
    Bar = 1,
}

fn f(foo: &Foo) -> u8 {
    *foo as u8
}
```

Since your enum will be a very lightweight object you should pass it around by value anyway, for which you would need `Copy` as well.

Comment: Expanding on this, without `Copy` the `*foo` is interpreted as moving the pointed-to value out of the shared reference passed to `f`.

Comment: Is there a way to cast an `enum` to an `int` without implementing `Copy` on the `enum`?

Comment: @Lukas Why do you need that? If you can cast it to an integer, the enum has no payload, so it is always possible to impl `Copy` for it.

Comment: I would hope that no actual copy of the `enum` is being made at runtime while turning it into an `int`, right? With the `clone/copy` traits, in this case, you just give permission to have the `enum` **immediately** duplicated into an `int`, correct?

Comment: @ErikBongers Yes. Copy in this case is merely a way to please the ownership logic (it could possibly do this behind the scene, for `enum`s that only map to copy-able values such as integers?). Think of it as getting - say - 3 copies of the `1` in different parts (registers, memory) in your program, at runtime. That is okay, I'm sure.