# How to do operator overloading on enums?

Tags: rust

I have an enum:

```
enum Numbers {
    A = 1,
}
```

How can I overload the operator so that I can compare the `Numbers` enum with another standard number without have to do `as u32`? If I want to do:

```
let a = Numbers::A < 4
```

I think i read somewhere that it's possible to do with some kind of macros? Maybe there is a crate that lets me do this? So far the only thing I have had success with is `as u32` but it gets quite tedious to have to write it out every time.

Comment: If you just want a constant, you could use a constant: `const A: u32 = 1`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You do it the exact same way that you overload an operator for a struct: implement the appropriate [`std::ops`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/ops/index.html) trait.

However, you don't really want to overload the meaning of `<`, you still wish to perform a comparison.

If you run the code you typed, the compiler *tells you what to do*:

```
error[E0369]: binary operation `<` cannot be applied to type `Numbers`
 --> src/main.rs:6:13
  |
6 |     let a = Numbers::A < 4;
  |             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  |
  = note: an implementation of `std::cmp::PartialOrd` might be missing for `Numbers`
```

So, implement [`PartialOrd`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/cmp/trait.PartialOrd.html):

```
#[derive(Copy, Clone)]
enum Numbers {
    A = 1,
}

use std::cmp::Ordering;

impl PartialEq<i32> for Numbers {
    fn eq(&self, other: &i32) -> bool {
        (*self as i32).eq(other)
    }
}

impl PartialOrd<i32> for Numbers {
    fn partial_cmp(&self, other: &i32) -> Option<Ordering> {
        (*self as i32).partial_cmp(other)
    }
}

fn main() {
    let a = Numbers::A < 4;
}
```

As [Sven Marnach points out](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53071935/how-to-do-operator-overloading-on-enums/53072328?noredirect=1#comment93066254_53072328):

> It may be worth pointing out that this implementation only allows comparisons with `Numbers` on the left-hand side and `i32` on the right-hand side. Comparisons like `4 > Numbers::A` and `Numbers.A < Numbers.B` would require separate implementations. In addition, since you are dealing with integers, you would also want to implement `Ord` and `Eq`, so for all combinations of operands you end up with twelve trait implementations.

Of course, it depends on your exact cases:

- if you want to compare `Numbers` to `Numbers`, you might be able to #[derive(PartialOrd)].
- if you want `Eq`, you can derive it.
- you can write macros to reduce some of the redundancy.

See also:

- [How do I convert an enum reference to a number?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/31358826/155423)
- [How do I implement the Add trait for a reference to a struct?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/28005134/155423)

Comment: It may be worth pointing out that this implementation only allows comparisons with `Numbers` on the left-hand side and `i32` on the right-hand side.  Comparisons like `4 > Numbers::A` and `Numbers.A < Numbers.B` would require separate implementations.  In addition, since you are dealing with integers, you would also want to implement `Ord` and `Eq`, so for all combinations of operands you end up with twelve trait implementations.