# How to implement a global and mutable HashMap with str as key and Trait as values?

Tags: rust, hashmap, global, traits, mutable

I am trying to implement value key pairs whose key would be a string and the value would be an object type that implements some predefined functions. The problem I encounter is that a Trait (which I use in this case as a kind of inheritance) does not have a predefined size and is not threads safely.

### Code

#### Create Trait and structs

```rust
/// _State line to define the basis of the 'State'
/// type with signatures of specific functions
pub trait _State {
    fn as_string(&self, text: String) -> String;
    fn print(&self);
}

/// Status type to add your custom colors
pub struct RGBState {
    name: String,
    color: (u8, u8, u8),
    character: String,
}

/// Default state type using preconfigured ANSI colors
pub struct State {
    name: String,
    color: Color,
    character: String,
}
```

#### Create a global and mutable HashMap with Traits as values

```rust
lazy_static! {
    static ref StateOK: Mutex<State> = {
        let mut state = State{
            name: String::from("OK"),
            color: Color::Green,
            character: "+".to_string()
        };
        Mutex::new(state)
    };

    static ref STATES: Mutex<HashMap<&'static str, &'static Lazy<Mutex<dyn _State + 'static>>>> = {
        let mut _states = HashMap::from(
            [
                (
                    "OK",
                    Lazy::new(StateOK)
                )
            ]
        );
        Mutex::new(_states)
    };
}
```

All source code is available on github (not compilable yiet): https://github.com/mauricelambert/TerminalMessages

### Context

I use the external library *lazy_static*.

### Assumptions

I guess I should use the Mutex, Lazy or other types that would allow me to make a mutable and global value.

### Problem

I have no idea how I will define the size of the objects that I will define in values and that can be of different types whose common basis are function signatures.

- I have at least 2 types of objects that implement the Trait and that can be added as a value: a 'simple' type with preconfigured colors and a more complex type or the colors are created by the developer with 3 octects (RGB - Red Green Blue).

### Project

The overall purpose of my code is to implement a DLL in Rust with interfaces in other languages that would allow to display formatted and colored messages in the console. Each element of the message formatting must be "configurable" by the developer (the color, the character that represents the type of message, the progress bar ect...). It must be able to use any of these message types by calling a function in which it will have to specify the message type and the content of the message.

#### Example/Demonstration

I implemented similar code in Python whose source code is on github: https://github.com/mauricelambert/PythonToolsKit/blob/main/PythonToolsKit/PrintF.py.
Here is a screenshot that represents what I would like to implement in this DLL: ![TerminalMessages demonstration](https://mauricelambert.github.io/info/python/code/PythonToolsKit/PrintF_demo.png)

### Additionally

I am interested in all the suggestions about Best Practices in Rust and Code Optimization.

Comment: Would you mind creating a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) that contains a `main` and `use` statements, so that we can just copy-paste it and play around with it?

Comment: You typically handle dynamic dispatch on a heterogeneous collection of objects implementing the same trait by putting them on the heap via smart pointers, like `Box<dyn SomeTrait>` or `Arc<dyn SomeTrait>`. These wrappers _are_ sized as they just contain a pointer to the heap.

Comment: I think this question is a borderline mix of [codereview](https://codereview.stackexchange.com) and opinion-based, but also has a problem that doesn't compile yet, so it is kind of suitable for SO ... but in general, I think it would be mor suitable for codereview.

Comment: After diddling around with your code a little, it *definitely* depends too heavily on code that is not shown here. Again, please provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). Missing in your code is: `impl _State for State`, `enum Color`, a `main` and `use` statements

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think there are a couple of misconceptions in your code, imo:

- To store trait objects in a `HashMap`, you need wrap them in a `Box`, because, as you already realized, trait objects are not `Sized`.
- You don't need to wrap the objects themselves in a `Mutex` because the entire `HashMap` is already in a `Mutex`.

With that in mind, here is a [working implementation](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=1ffe4402bae1485350dbdbee34eb9a46):

```rust
use std::{collections::HashMap, sync::Mutex};

use lazy_static::lazy_static;

/// Preconfigured ANSI colors constants
#[derive(Clone)]
pub enum Color {
    Black,  // 0
    Red,    // 1
    Green,  // 2
    Yellow, // 3
    Blue,   // 4
    Purple, // 5
    Cyan,   // 6
    White,  // 7
}

impl Color {
    fn value(&self) -> i32 {
        match *self {
            Color::Black => 0,
            Color::Red => 1,
            Color::Green => 2,
            Color::Yellow => 3,
            Color::Blue => 4,
            Color::Purple => 5,
            Color::Cyan => 6,
            Color::White => 7,
        }
    }
}

/// _State line to define the basis of the 'State'
/// type with signatures of specific functions
pub trait _State {
    fn as_string(&self, text: String) -> String;
    fn print(&self);
}

/// Default state type using preconfigured ANSI colors
#[derive(Clone)]
pub struct State {
    name: String,
    color: Color,
    character: String,
}

impl _State for State {
    fn as_string(&self, text: String) -> String {
        format!(
            "\x1b[3{color}m[{character}] {text}\x1b[0m",
            color = self.color.value(),
            character = self.character,
            text = text,
        )
    }

    fn print(&self) {
        println!("{}", self.as_string(self.name.clone()));
    }
}

lazy_static! {
    static ref STATE_OK: State = {
        State {
            name: String::from("OK"),
            color: Color::Green,
            character: "+".to_string(),
        }
    };
    static ref STATES: Mutex<HashMap<&'static str, Box<dyn _State + Send>>> = {
        let _states: HashMap<&'static str, Box<dyn _State + Send>> = HashMap::from([
            ("OK", Box::new(STATE_OK.clone()) as Box<dyn _State + Send>),
            (
                "NOK",
                Box::new(State {
                    name: String::from("NOK"),
                    color: Color::Yellow,
                    character: "-".to_string(),
                }) as Box<dyn _State + Send>,
            ),
        ]);
        Mutex::new(_states)
    };
}

fn main() {
    println!("{}", STATES.lock().unwrap().len());
    for (key, value) in &*STATES.lock().unwrap() {
        println!("{}:", key);
        value.print();
        println!("");
    }
}
```

---

### Further tweaks

Those are more my opinion, take them or leave them.

- Make `trait _State` depend on `Send`, as they all have to be `Send` to be storable in the `HashMap`. This makes the `HashMap` definition a little cleaner
- write `state_entry` helper function to simplify initialization

```rust
use std::{collections::HashMap, sync::Mutex};

use lazy_static::lazy_static;

/// Preconfigured ANSI colors constants
#[derive(Clone)]
pub enum Color {
    Black,  // 0
    Red,    // 1
    Green,  // 2
    Yellow, // 3
    Blue,   // 4
    Purple, // 5
    Cyan,   // 6
    White,  // 7
}

impl Color {
    fn value(&self) -> i32 {
        match *self {
            Color::Black => 0,
            Color::Red => 1,
            Color::Green => 2,
            Color::Yellow => 3,
            Color::Blue => 4,
            Color::Purple => 5,
            Color::Cyan => 6,
            Color::White => 7,
        }
    }
}

/// _State line to define the basis of the 'State'
/// type with signatures of specific functions
pub trait _State: Send {
    fn as_string(&self, text: String) -> String;
    fn print(&self);
}

/// Default state type using preconfigured ANSI colors
#[derive(Clone)]
pub struct State {
    name: String,
    color: Color,
    character: String,
}

impl _State for State {
    fn as_string(&self, text: String) -> String {
        format!(
            "\x1b[3{color}m[{character}] {text}\x1b[0m",
            color = self.color.value(),
            character = self.character,
            text = text,
        )
    }

    fn print(&self) {
        println!("{}", self.as_string(self.name.clone()));
    }
}

fn state_entry(
    name: &'static str,
    entry: impl _State + 'static,
) -> (&'static str, Box<dyn _State>) {
    (name, Box::new(entry))
}

lazy_static! {
    static ref STATE_OK: State = {
        State {
            name: String::from("OK"),
            color: Color::Green,
            character: "+".to_string(),
        }
    };
    static ref STATES: Mutex<HashMap<&'static str, Box<dyn _State>>> = {
        Mutex::new(HashMap::from([
            state_entry("OK", STATE_OK.clone()),
            state_entry(
                "NOK",
                State {
                    name: String::from("NOK"),
                    color: Color::Yellow,
                    character: "-".to_string(),
                },
            ),
            state_entry(
                "ERROR",
                State {
                    name: String::from("ERROR"),
                    color: Color::Red,
                    character: "!".to_string(),
                },
            ),
        ]))
    };
}

fn main() {
    println!("{} entries\n", STATES.lock().unwrap().len());

    for (key, value) in &*STATES.lock().unwrap() {
        println!("{}:", key);
        value.print();
        println!("");
    }
}
```

Comment: For the Color enum, you can just specify the values with `= 0` syntax (or leave it off, since 0, 1, 2, etc is the default, and in Color::value you can do `as i32`. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31358826/how-do-i-convert-an-enum-reference-to-a-number

Comment: @hkBst That's just copy paste from his code in the linked repository